# Error 2003 when analyzing results for Custom Model

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Using this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/curl-train-extract I follow each step and use the sample data in the guide. All of them are successful until the last step which is "Get the Analyze results", where it returns the following:

```
{
    "status": "failed",
    "createdDateTime": "2020-07-09T14:59:12Z",
    "lastUpdatedDateTime": "2020-07-09T14:59:14Z",
    "analyzeResult": {
        "version": null,
        "readResults": null,
        "pageResults": null,
        "documentResults": null,
        "errors": [
            {
                "code": "2003",
                "message": "Download failed. Please check your input URL."
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, there are no references to error codes and possible explanation/solutions. Assistance is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is quite clear: the url that you provided for the analysis does not allow the service to download the document.

Please check the content that you sent during the operation called "Analyze forms for key-value pairs and tables":

```
curl -v "https://<Endpoint>/formrecognizer/v2.0/custom/models/<model ID>/analyze" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: <subscription key>" -d "{ \"source\": \""<SAS URL>"\" } "
```

In particular, can you detail the last part? The piece with the '' block is the one causing the error

Comment: I have sent the content as specified in "Analyze forms for key-value pairs and tables" and I get 202 Accepted. When creating the "Shared Access Signature" I specified the Read and List permissions.

I didn't get you about the detail in the last part. Which piece is causing the issue?

Comment: Double check your Sas url. You can get a 202 as soon as your payload is correct, the capacity to download the document is not tested before sending this 202